# name 'Path' is not defined

Tags: python-3.9

Here you can see the Python-code. As output then always appears: name 'Path' is not defined.

```
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

f = open("test_filedialog.txt", "w")
f.close()

 

def openfile():
    Path=filedialog.askopenfilenames(title ="Datein auswählen", filetypes=[("CSV-Datein", "*.csv"),("alle Datein", "*.*")]).open("test_filedialog.txt", "w")
    f = open("test_filedialog.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(Path))
    f.close()
    


x = tk.Tk()
title= x.title("Titelleiste")


label1=tk.Label(x, text="Hallo", width=25, height=5)
label1.pack()

button1=tk.Button (x, text="Exit",width= 10, height=1, command=x.destroy)
button1.pack()

button2=tk.Button (x, text= "open file", width= 15, height=2, command=openfile)
button2.pack()


    
x.mainloop()

#import matplotlib import pyplot as plt

daten=pd.read_csv(Path, header=None, sep=';',)                                  #liest jetzt ausgewählte Spalten ein --> Die Frage ist wie wir das für Spaltenbereiche machen


df=daten.drop(range (2),axis=1)
new_header=df.iloc[0]

df=df[1:]

df.columns=new_header

auswahl=df.loc[:,158.936:159.01]

print(auswahl)
    

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = testApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

`

I tried to define the 'Path' as an extra class. But unfortunately this did not lead to any result.

It would be nice if you have a solution for the problem. Maybe how to define the 'Path' as an extra class but also another solution would be ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python a variable defined inside a function does not have global scope. You shoud define a Path variable that is path to a csv file. You have error at line 38.

```
import pandas as pd
path = './data.csv' # path to csv file

df = pd.read_csv(path) 
print(df.to_string())
```

Actually I should have tried to run the script.I have not fixed the error.

```
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd


def read_csv(Path):
    daten=pd.read_csv(Path, header=None, sep=',',) 
    print(daten)

    # df=daten.drop(range (2),axis=1)
    # new_header=df.iloc[0]

    # df=df[1:]

    # df.columns=new_header

    # auswahl=df.loc[:,158.936:159.01]

    # print(auswahl)

def openfile():
    Path=filedialog.askopenfilenames(title ="Datein auswählen", filetypes=[("CSV-Datein", "*.csv"),("alle Datein", "*.*")])[0]
    read_csv(Path) # do file operation in this function


x = tk.Tk()
title= x.title("Titelleiste")


label1=tk.Label(x, text="Hallo", width=25, height=5)
label1.pack()

button1=tk.Button (x, text="Exit",width= 10, height=1, command=x.destroy)
button1.pack()

button2=tk.Button (x, text= "open file", width= 15, height=2, command=openfile)
button2.pack()


    
x.mainloop()

#import matplotlib import pyplot as plt


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk()
    # app = testApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The askopenfile function does not return an object but a tupple with file names. Also you should do file operations in openfile function. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.
Unfortunately, there is now the problem that our 'Path' is no longer variable. So now you can no longer select any file via the user interface.

Comment: I have now fixed the code now. sample csv file https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/grades.csv